# Using a function to access and edit objects from multiple classes

Tags: c++

I am attempting to use objects from two classes in an outside function that I can call into main. I want this function to use methods to access and edit the objects as well

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    private:
        int attrib;
        
    public:
        int getAttrib();
        void setAttrib(int);
        
        Test();
        
        //Test *object;
};

Test::Test()
{
    attrib = 0;
}

int Test::getAttrib()
{
    return attrib;
}

void Test::setAttrib(int _attrib)
{
    attrib = _attrib;
    cout << endl << "Test set opened" << endl;
}

class Test2
{
    private:
        char character;
        
    public:
        char getCharacter();
        void setCharacter(char);
        
        Test2();
        
        //Test2 *object2;
};

Test2::Test2()
{
    character = 'a';
}

char Test2::getCharacter()
{
    return character;
}

void Test2::setCharacter(char _character)
{
    character = _character;
    cout << endl << "Test2 set opened" << endl;
}

void setting(Test object, Test2 object2)
{
    cout << endl << "Success" << endl;
    
    object.setAttrib(1);
    object2.setCharacter('A');
    
    cout << object.getAttrib() << endl;
        cout << object2.getCharacter() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test object;
    Test2 object2;
    
    cout << "Construct: " << object.getAttrib() << " " << object2.getCharacter() << endl;
    
    setting(object, object2);
    
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Function: " << object.getAttrib() << " " << object2.getCharacter() << endl;
    
    object.setAttrib(2);
    object2.setCharacter('b');
    
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Method: " << object.getAttrib() << " " << object2.getCharacter() << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Right now the program outputs the objects and they change in the function, but the objects do not change outside of the function

Comment: read about pass by value vs pass by reference.

Comment: *but the objects do not change outside of the function* -- This is no different than doing this: `void foo(int x) { x = 10; }  int main() { int x = 100; foo(x); }` you will see that `x` is still 100 after the call to `foo`, even though in `foo`, there is an `x` that was changed to `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that objects change not only in the settings function:

```
void setting(Test &object, Test2 &object2)
```

Comment: I would consider a function with two in/out parameters a design issue.